# Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object while consuming messages from Kafka topic

Tags: json, kotlin, apache-kafka, micronaut

I am trying to consume messages from kafka-topic in which json contents are not serialized. The topic has been produced with actual JSON without serialization like below.

JSON:

```
{
  "guests": [
    {
      "guest_ref_id": "000000012331202",
      "ids": {
        "profile_ids": [
          "1234"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "case_id": "500g000000Tw5ggAAB",
  "case_creation_ts": 1580512345,
  "state_of_origin": "CA"
}
```

Now, when I try to consume the message from the topic using below configuration and listener-code, I am getting serialization exception as `Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object`

**application.yml**

```
topics:
  input:
    datasource: test-topic
---
kafka:
  bootstrap:
    servers: localhost:9092
  consumers:
    consumer:
      key:
        deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value:
        deserializer: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer
```

**Listener Code:**

```
    @Topic(value = ["\${topics.input.datasource}"])
    fun receiveNotifications(
        @Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") @KafkaKey keys: List<String?>,
        @MessageBody notifications: List<GuestDTO>,
        topics: List<String>,
        partitions: List<Int>,
        offsets: List<Long>,
        kafkaConsumer: Consumer<String, GuestDTO>
    ) = runBlocking {
        notifications.forEach { notification ->
            // business logic
        }
        logger.info("Delete Request Processed -> Commiting Offset")
        kafkaConsumer.commitSync()
    }

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy::class)
data class GuestDTO(
    var guests: List<Guest>? = null,
    var caseId: String = ""
)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy::class)
data class Guest(
    var guestRefId: String = "",
    var ids: Map<String, List<String>>? = null
)
```

I am not sure exactly how to handle this, the above setup works when the json messages are serialized and produced to the topic without any issues.
But the catch is there is no control over for me to produce the serialized JSON message. So, looking for a way to consume non-serialized JSON messages from kafka topics. Thanks in advance for the help to be provided!

Comment: By definition, JSON is a serialized object notation. What do you mean messages "are not serialized"? Or "actual JSON without serialization"?

Answer (score 1):

If the data isn't valid JSON, then you must use StringDeserializer, then try-catch the JSON parsing yourself.

Your other option is to introduce a Schema Registry, but if you don't control the producers, then it won't fully solve the problem

Comment: I see, that when pretty printed json is sent to kafka topic, it is not sent in one single-line (as one record) rather than as multiple records, hence I faced the above problem. When I asked the consumer end to send the json as one record, it resolved the problem.